# Как лучше реализовать графический интерфейс?

Tags: c#, c++

У меня есть готовое консольное приложение на С++, задача которого — кое-что посчитать. Я хочу прикрутить к этому графический интерфейс. Что будет лучше сделать: написать интерфейс на С# и с помощью всяких страшных конструкций передавать значения между программными модулями на разных языках, или просто переписать всю программу на С#? И стоит ли мне в будущем стараться использовать только один язык, или это некритично?

Comment: Вам стоит обратить внимание на Qt. Это весьма неплохой фреймворк для создания настольных и других приложений